# integral substitution not by u-sub

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2 +4x+9)}\,dx$$
Just playing around with this integral ,is it possible to do this integral by trig substitution?
 I would personally just go by completing the square then doign u-sub, but is trig sub possible here?

Comment: Yes, trig sub is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2 +4x+9)}\,dx =\int\frac{1}{(x+2)^2 +5}\,dx $$

The trig substitution $$ (x+2)=\sqrt 5 \tan(t)$$ would do.